# cannot detect div's radio button no output is produced only can detect the main radio button

Tags: python, html, flask

hi guys i tried to run a simple program using python flux and html. Im able to detect the first 2 radio button which is "Bitcoin Address" and "a transaction hash". But im not able to detect the last 3 radio button "Dual Mode", "Address Network" and "Transaction Network". when i say cant detect means after selecting the 3 div radio buttons (any of it) it will return me with no result can someone help me please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!----<style>
      body { </b>ackground: url(https://specials-images.forbesimg.com/imageserve/5e00d824e961e1000739c13a/960x0.jpg?fit=scale); background-size:100%; }
    </style>--->
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: double;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The grid: Three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.containerTab {
  padding: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;

}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Closable button inside the container tab */
.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: black;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


</style>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <br>
    <span style="font-size: 250%"><center> Bitcoin Dashboard </center></span><br>
    <input style="font-size:15px;" type="text" name="transactionid" size="60" placeholder="Enter a Bitcoin address/transaction">
    &emsp;This is: 
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id ="BitcoinAddr" value="bitcoin" checked> 
    <label for="BitcoinAddr">Bitcoin Address</label>
    &emsp;
    <input style="font-size:20px;" type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    Search depth:
    <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="1" max="10" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
    <input style="font-size:15px;" type="text" id="textInput" value="5">
    &emsp;&emsp;&ensp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;

    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="TrHash" value="transaction">
    <label for="TrHash">a transaction hash</label><br><br><br>
</form>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b1');" style="background:grey;">Plot</div>
  <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b2');" style="background:grey;">Filter Edges</div>
  <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b3');" style="background:grey;">Find Paths</div>
  <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b4');" style="background:grey;">Cluster</div>
  <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b5');" style="background:grey;">Neighbours</div>
</div>



<!------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- The expanding grid (hidden by default) -->
<div id="b1" class="containerTab" style="background:white">
  <!-- If you want the ability to close the container, add a close button -->
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">x</span>
  <form method="post">
    <span style="float: left"><b>View: </b></span>
    <center><b> Zoom: <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="1" max="10" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value);"><input style="font-size:15px;" type="text" id="textInput1" value="5"></b>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;  
    <b><input style="font-size:20px;" type="checkbox" name="Label" value="Label"> Labels</b>&emsp;
    <input style="font-size:20px;" type="submit" value="Submit"></center>

    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="DualMode" value="DualMode" checked>
    <label for="DualMode">Dual Mode</label><br>

    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="AddrNet" value="AddrNet">
    <label for="AddrNet">Address Network</label><br>
    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="TrNet" value="TrNet">
    <label for="TrNet">Transaction Network</label>
    <br><br>
    <div>
      {{outputresult}}
<!--     {% if result != None %}
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ outputresult }}"\>
    {% endif %} -->
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

im using flask to link with HTML.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
import base64 #enconder, encodes the graph into html strings
from io import BytesIO # converter, convert the data into the encoder strings
from flask import Flask
from neo4j import GraphDatabase #Graphdatabase for Neo4j
from neo4j.types.graph import Node, Relationship
import networkx as nx #graph plotting tool for neo4j,create the graph without display
import time
import matplotlib as plt #displaying the graph that is plotted by networkx
plt.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    # if form.validate_on_submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      if 'transactionid' in request.form:
          option = request.form['gender'] 
          option1 = request.form['gender']
          if option == "bitcoin" and option1 == "DualMode":
          # transactionaddr = request.form['transactionid']
          # newresult = generateAndConvertGraph(transactionaddr)
                newresult = "bitcoin and DualMode"
                return render_template('home.html', outputresult=newresult)
          elif option == "bitcoin" and option1 == "AddrNet":
                newresult = "bitcoin and Adress Network"
                return render_template('home.html', outputresult=newresult)
          elif option == "bitcoin" and option1 == "TrNet":
                newresult = "bitcoin and Transaction address"
                return render_template('home.html', outputresult=newresult)
          else:
            newresult = "cant detect div radio button"
            return render_template('home.html', outputresult=newresult)

      elif 'BTCamt' in request.form:
          BTCaddr = request.form['BTCamt']
          newresult = generateAndConvertGraph(BTCaddr)
          return render_template('home.html', outBTC=newresult)

    return render_template('home.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have two `@app.route( "/")`'s. one which does handle the GET and POST requests and one that doesnt. Applying another route to the actual form 'handler' would be a good idea here. If only for clarity.
Your route could look like this:

```
@app.route("/form_handler", methods=['GET','POST'])
```

Secondly, maybe it has something to do with not setting an action attribute of "form". The action attribute defines which page should be redirected to and which route the form should be posted to when submitted. 
This could help: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp. 
The value of the action attribute in your case should be: `"/"`. If using the route like said above it should be: `"/form_handler"`.

your form should look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/form_handler">
```

Hope this will help.